# Nested MySQL query failed with `Error Code 1060 Duplicate column name 'xxx'`

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I have three tables: `tabe_1, table_2, table_3`, I'm going to use a field `A` to map the first two tables, since it is included in both  `table_1` and `table_2`, then join with `table_3` with field `B` and `C`, then add some filters (e.g: `where` statement) on top of that, the query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(select *
from table_1 t1 
join table_2 t2 
on t1.A = t2.A
join table_3 t3
on t1.B  = t3.B 
and t1.C = t3.C) AS output_table

WHERE output_table.xx = xxx
```

This gave me error: `Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'A'`

But if I only query the subquery:

```
select *
from table_1 t1 
join table_2 t2 
on t1.A = t2.A
join table_3 t3
on t1.B  = t3.B 
and t1.C = t3.C
```

This will return the output_table, can someone take a look what is going on with the nested query? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use `select *` in the subquery.  List the columns in the subquery.

Comment: Yes please see the query above: `FROM (select * from.......) AS output_table`

Comment: List the column in the subquery rather than using `select *`.  I think my earlier comment got all jumbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you SQL query need the ability to distinct subquery fields in order to treat it as a table type record source.

Here is an example of what's happen :

```sql
with table_1 as (select 0 A, 0 B, 0 C),
     table_2 as (select 0 A, 0 D),
     table_3 as (select 1 A, 0 B, 0 C)
SELECT *
FROM 
(select *
from table_1 t1 
join table_2 t2 
on t1.A = t2.A
join table_3 t3
on t1.B  = t3.B 
and t1.C = t3.C) AS output_table
WHERE output_table.D = 0;
```

This fails because the subquery has field t1.A/t1.B/t1.C **and** t2.A/t2.D **and** t3.A/t3.B/t3.C.

If you don't make it a subquery, then the MySQL engine doesn't need to distinct the fields and can output records with all fields indistinctively.
From your case, the query that works :

```sql
with table_1 as (select 0 A, 0 B, 0 C),
     table_2 as (select 0 A, 0 D),
     table_3 as (select 1 A, 0 B, 0 C)
select *
from table_1 t1 
join table_2 t2 
on t1.A = t2.A
join table_3 t3
on t1.B  = t3.B 
and t1.C = t3.C;
```

So, to avoid the problem, select precisely what fields you requires from your subquery, like that :

```sql
with table_1 as (select 0 A, 0 B, 0 C),
     table_2 as (select 0 A, 0 D),
     table_3 as (select 1 A, 0 B, 0 C)
SELECT *
FROM 
(select t1.*, t2.D
from table_1 t1 
join table_2 t2 
on t1.A = t2.A
join table_3 t3
on t1.B  = t3.B 
and t1.C = t3.C) AS output_table
WHERE output_table.D = 0;
```

To be more clear, imagine that you want to join another table with your subquery (`(subquery) AS output_table join another_table t4 on t4.A = output_table.A`, how the MySQL engine can determine which field A from output_table it should use to join with another_table between t1.A (0) and T3.A (1) ? It can't, unless you specify only one field 'A' in your subquery.

Answer (score 1):

In your subquery, you have column A & column A in t1 & t2, so there is ambiguity.
Try alias name for the column, that should make things easy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `table_1` and `table_2` have at least one column which exists in both tables (your column `A`). Thus when your subquery executes as `select * from ...` it returns two columns with the same name. This is not a problem if you just do this subquery alone, but you cannot query from the result of that subquery

Rewrite your subquery to

```
select t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t2.whatever, t3.idontknow, ...
....
```

and make sure, to select the columns you are joining on (or that exists in mor than one table) only from one table.